# Compare two dataframes to produce one final with all present values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'd like to know how to combine two dataframes into one only that has all present values such that:

```
df_t = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": ["a", "a", "b", "c", None],
        "col2": [1.0, None, 3.0, None, 5.0],
        "col3": [1.0, None, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
    },
    columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"],
)

df_t_+_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [None, "a", "b", "c", "d"],
        "col2": [1.0, None, 3.0, 8.2, 5.0],
        "col3": [None, 2.3, 3.0, None, 5.0]
    },
    columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"],
)
```

I'd like to combine both dataframes so that I get a final dataframe like:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": ["a", "a", "b", "c", "d"],
        "col2": [1.0, None, 3.0, 8.2, 5.0],
        "col3": [1.0, 2.3, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
    },
    columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"],
)
```

I'm basically replacing all None values by values that is present in each dataframe. If there's a None in the df2, don't replace with None if there was already a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df_t.fillna(df_t_p_1)
```

output

```
    col1 col2 col3
0   a   1.0 1.0
1   a   NaN 2.3
2   b   3.0 3.0
3   c   8.2 4.0
4   d   5.0 5.0
```

where I renamed the illegally named second df:

```
df_t_p_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [None, "a", "b", "c", "d"],
        "col2": [1.0, None, 3.0, 8.2, 5.0],
        "col3": [None, 2.3, 3.0, None, 5.0]
    },
    columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"],
)
```